# HtmlUnitdriver issues with Ajax content, I think

Tags: selenium, asynchronous, htmlunit

I have been testing an app using Firefox Web Driver but it is really slow comparing with HtmlUnitdriver, so I decided to translate to last one. All works fine but I have problems with some kind of  links that loads information async.

In my case it is not problem of "wait" because I do and as i said before, using Firefox driver works very well. But with HtmlUnit doesnt work well.

In my scene I have following code:

```
<a href="/requests?category=challenge" data-method="post" data-remote="true" id="759" rel="nofollow">Send</a>
```

Viewing the app on a browser such as Firefox, when I click on that link, the system return me a result. But when I use HtmlUnitdriver, when I do click to the element, the driver goes directly to the href and then I have a bad result.

I don't really know how to do make works with it. I'm really interested on this way because is really fast.

Comment: Have you tried using PhantomJSDriver?  That is a selenium headless driver which should accomplish the same thing with the same selenium code, but a different driver.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks for your answer. I will try and will put my results.

Comment: I would try the latest htmlunit version and ask the htmlunit users list https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/htmlunit-user with a concrete code

Comment: Thanks for all your answer. Finally I done with PhantomJSDriver that is really fast. Also I made a HtmlUnitDriver and now works passing to the constructor function "true".